# Expand All / Collapse All / Expand All of Type / Collapse All of Type

Tags: best-practice, selling-ux

I have a specific "expand/collapse" problem that I'm pretty sure I have the best solution to, but my collaborator is calling "clunky."

The particular view I'm designing is similar to the interface of Google Docs, but with a different subject matter. It takes sections from uploaded documents (such as pdfs) and displays them as a list of expandable sections - so you'll have a bar with section number, section title and an expand/collapse arrow. Users of this application can open these sections and suggest rules to apply to the content within a section. Above all the sections, we want to have buttons for expand all / collapse all, which is simple enough, however we also want "expand sections with suggestions only" and "collapse sections with suggestions only."

My suggestion is to have the two buttons for "expand all" and "collapse all," with a checkbox next to it saying "only sections with suggestions" or something similar. So it would be:

[image]

Now, while I believe the wording after the checkbox needs a little work, it seems like a more elegant solution to having 4 different expand/collapse buttons.

My overall questions are:

1. Do people agree with me that this is an elegant solution? (I'm sort of questioning myself now)
2. If so, are there any suggestions for how to sell the idea as the best solution besides each of us just saying the other person's idea is more clunky.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi jtomeck, it would be easier to understand this with a visual mockup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picturing this visually I would say it will be hard for the user to guess that the checkbox refers to the buttons. That is not a familiar concept.

I would go more in the direction of having a segmented button with a dropdown to have a secondary "Expand/Collapse only sections with suggestions".
[image]

Comment: This is a great thought! Thanks for this, I will get this implemented in my mockups. What I like is that it also easily gives me the ability to add the option "expand all sections without suggestions" in case a user wants to leave their own suggestions rather than reviewing others'. I've also edited my original post to include a screenshot of my original thought.